# Affecting one object in array p5.js - Javascript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

*Using p5 libraries, with p5 editor.*
I'm trying to change the colour of a 'bubble' in an array of 'bubbles' however, when I click on a bubble it changes all of the bubbles colours.

The `glow()` function is the one that changes the colour and the `mousePressed()` function checks to see if you have clicked the mouse.

```
var bubbles = [];
var bubbleNum = 10; //The number of bubbles on the screen

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000, 800);
    for (let i = 0; i < bubbleNum; i++) {
        let x = map(i, 0, bubbleNum, 0, width);
        bubbles[i] = new Bubble(x, random(0, height), 30);
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(50);
    for (let i = 0; i < bubbleNum; i++) {
        bubbles[i].show();
        if (mouseIsPressed) {
            for (let i = 0; i < bubbleNum; i++) {
                bubbles[i].move();
            }
        }
    }
}

function mousePressed() {
    for (let i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++) {
        bubbles[i].glow(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}

class Bubble {
    constructor(x, y, r) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
    }

    move() {
        this.x = this.x + random(-1, 1);
        this.y = this.y + random(-1, 1);
    }

    show() {
        noStroke();
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r, this.r);
    }

    glow(mx, my) {
        let d = dist(mx, my, this.x, this.y);
        if (d < this.r) {
            fill(244, 220, 66);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You made a small mistake, but it took me a while to get it as well :P In your `glow` function you set the global colour, not for a single bubble.

So I propose to adapt your `Bubble` class as follows: remember the colour of the bubble, and then when doing the `show` of all bubbles, you draw the bubble in the assigned colour, depending on whether or not it was clicked.

```
class Bubble {
    constructor(x, y, r) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
        this.color = color(255,255,255);
    }

    move() {
        this.x = this.x + random(-1, 1);
        this.y = this.y + random(-1, 1);
    }

    show() {
        noStroke();
        fill(this.color);
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r, this.r);
    }

    glow(mx, my) {
        let d = dist(mx, my, this.x, this.y);
        if (d < this.r) {
            this.color = color(244, 220, 66);
        }
    }
}
```

See [example](http://alpha.editor.p5js.org/nathanvda/sketches/ryrCLNPnG)